# How to check whether an Integer is null or zero in Java?

Tags: java

Is there more concise way to write:

```
if (myInteger != null && myInteger != 0) { ... }
```

For example, for Strings you can use `StringUtils.isBlank()`

Comment: @RafałLaskowski that depends on the type, i.e. `int` vs. `Integer` (the latter _can_ be null).

Comment: @RafałLaskowski He/she meant `Integer` not `int`

Comment: Is `myInteger` of type `int` or `Integer`? If it's the first then it cannot be `null`.

Comment: @skw: Given both the title of the question and the name of the variable, it seems pretty clear it's `Integer`.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't any way to do those checks with one operation but you could provide/use a utility method e.g. `if( notNullOrZero( myInteger ) ) { ... } `

Comment: @MykhayloAdamovych `StringUtils.isBlank()` is from apache commons. Are you asking us whether there is a library which contains a one-line method instead of just writing it yourself?

Comment: lets apache forum make a note of this to upgrade!! :)

Comment: Not as far as I know. While you could easily define your static utility method to do that, I would not do that, since that would give the value 0 a special meaning that is questionable (even though it exists e.g. in C/C++). It seems that you are using myInteger as an optional value. If that's the case, and you're in Java 8, then you can use an Optional<Integer> and write `if (myOptInteger.orElse(0) != 0)`

Comment: You are talking in a manner that empty string could not have special meaning alongside with null...

Comment: You can do something like `if(Objects.nonNull(myInteger) && myInteger.intValue()!=0)`. Objects has two method `nonNull` & `isNull`, you can use these methods for null check but instead of use these methods I believe `myInteger != null` option is better.

Comment: I would write it exactly as you have now; it'll be clearer than any alternative.

Comment: I would like to have single-word Apache util method

Comment: I believe that would be a rare case. But the method could be named this way: `Integers.nonZero(number)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since `StringUtils` class is mentioned in the question, I assume that Apache Commons lib is already used in the project.

Then you can use the following:

```
if (0 != ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull(myInteger, 0)) { ... }
```

Or using static import:

```
if (0 != defaultIfNull(myInteger, 0)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 37):

With Java 8:

```
if (Optional.ofNullable(myInteger).orElse(0) != 0) {
  ...
}
```

Note that `Optional` may help you to completely avoid the if condition at all, depending on your use case...

Comment: Yep, agree that this is longer than the "ugly plain" solution. But that's why I made the addition that Optional may help to avoid these checks at all...

Comment: this still fails to check for myInteger not being null & will fail with NullPointerException. Since the target object is Integer, we have to check for both not null and not Zero.

Comment: Even though this solution is not really any more "concise" than the one in the OP, the use of an `Optional` really opens doors that I didn't know existed - especially if the object is more than just a primitive wrapper.

Comment: This condition can be a bit less without intValue() :) `if (Optional.ofNullable(myInteger).orElse(0) != 0) { ....`

Comment: @VladimirGilevich Thanks for the hint! I am no big fan of autoboxing, as you'll never know what the compiler makes out of it, but yes, in this case, it does even increase readability.

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht or a bit another variant then: `if (!Optional.ofNullable(myInteger).orElse(0).equals(0)) { ....`

Comment: @VladimirGilevich That's also autoboxing (both zeroes are autoboxed to Integer objects). What highlights the point that my previous solution also used autoboxing (in the orElse call)...

Answer (score 6):

I would use a ternary condition for this. Something like :

```
public static boolean isNullorZero(Integer i){
    return 0 == ( i == null ? 0 : i);
}
```

This is not readable, I agree ;)

Comment: i==null || i==0 wont it be easy :P

Answer (score 2):

```
private boolean isNullOrZero(Integer i){
     return i == null || i.intValue() == 0;
}
```

For some other types:

`i.longValue() == 0` for Long

`i.doubleValue() == 0` for Double

`i.shortValue() == 0` for Short

`i.floatValue() == 0` for Float

Answer (score 2):

There is also a nullsafe way to do it like:

```
Long val = null;
if( val == Long.valueOf( 0 ) ) {...}
```

or

```
if( Objects.equals( val, 0L ) ) {...}
```

Comment: Note that the first code example using `valueOf(0)` only works for values between -127 and 128.  People considering this technique shouldn't assume that it will work in general.

Comment: @Parakleta in fact it works for bigger integers `System.out.println(999999999l == Long.valueOf( 999999999 ));`
I remember learning about long pools in the range [-128:127] but it seems this is not the case for java 11.

Comment: what you have written is not the same as the first code example.  Try again with `Long val = 999999999l; System.out.println(val == Long.valueOf(999999999));`.  The difference here is that your example in the comment actually unboxes the `Long` to do a primitve `long` comparison.

Comment: @Parakleta yeah, you a right, missed that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I created a helper method that maybe can help you, it uses reflection so you have to think if is necessary to use it, also you need java 8.

The method is for all java numbers:

```
 public class NumberUtils {

    private NumberUtils(){
    }

    public static  < T extends Number>  T getNumberOrZero(T number, Class<? extends Number> clazz) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(number)
                .orElse(getZeroValue(clazz));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static < T extends Number> T getZeroValue( Class<? extends Number> clazz){
        try{
            Constructor<? extends Number> constructor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class);
            return (T) constructor.newInstance("0");
        }catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't get zero value ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

You can call in this way:

```
Integer myNumber = NumberUtils.getNumberOrZero(someIntegerThatCanBeNull, Integer.class);
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your implementation of `myInteger` (i.e. if the Integer property within `myInteger` is the box type `Integer` or the unboxed primitive `int`), you may only have to write one conditional.

`Integer`s are actual objects, which means they have the ability to be `null`.  That being said they can also hold 0 as a value.  So, in this case you would have to make both checks.

`int` is a primitive and cannot hold the value of `null`.  In this case you would only have to check if your `int` property is not equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectUtils.nullSafeEquals(0, myInteger)` would be good to use if you don't want to increase cyclomatic complexity AND still get the functionality of myInteger.equals(0) while handling null values appropriatly.

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isNotNullAndZero(Long num){
        return Optional.ofNullable(num).orElse(0L) != 0L ? true:false;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `Long` if the question is about integers? Sure, the question doesn't specify whether it means integers in the general sense, or in the sense of the width-specific sense, but either way, why `Long`?

Comment: Writing `? true : false` is almost **always** completely superfluous. Never do that. And after that, your answer is almost completely identical to mine.